# openlayers2 map rightclick menu

Tags: javascript, openlayers

i want add a menu on my map when right click, i try lots of ways, but do not work.
   one way like follow, but not work
   i register a onMapRightClick function to rightclick, but when i right click the map, it do not response

Code in openlayer event.js

```
 BROWSER_EVENTS: [
    "mouseover", "mouseout",
    "mousedown", "mouseup", "mousemove", 
    "click", "dblclick", "rightclick", "dblrightclick",
    "resize", "focus", "blur",
    "touchstart", "touchmove", "touchend",
    "keydown"
],
```

code in my js file

```
 map.events.register("rightclick", map, onMapRightClick);

 function onMapRightClick(e){
 var str = map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(e.xy);
 Ext.MessageBox.show("",str.lat + " " + str.lon);
 };
```

if there exist a way can help me

Answer (score 0):

You can have your eventhandler listen to the 'mouseup' event and use OpenLayers built in functionality to determine if it was a rightclick. Remember to disable the contextmenu on your map element.

```
// Disable the context menu on your map element.
var mapElement = document.querySelector("#map");
mapElement.oncontextmenu = function () { return false };

// Create the map and add your event listener.
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
map.events.register('mouseup', map, onMapRightClick);

function onMapRightClick(e) {

  // Check if it is a right click event.
    if (OpenLayers.Event.isRightClick(e)) {
      var str = map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(e.xy);
      Ext.MessageBox.show("",str.lat + " " + str.lon);
    }
}
```